# Problems with IndexPath in the tableView reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing such a trouble, let's go:

I have a tableView which has been loaded with a array of arrays, this process have worked perfectly, however, when I update that tableView (reload), even using the same array and the scroll is posicioned in half of list, or in the end, it seems the indexes are loaded wrongly, that is, when a cell is loaded, the information of another cell is loaded. On the other hand, if the scroll is on the top of tableview, that is, in the first cell, even in reload process, this problem does not happen, bellow my code:

Thanks so much!

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell_aux";

clsTableViewCell *cell = (clsTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell_aux" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (clsTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

arInfos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[arMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]                  componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

[arInfosAll addObject:arInfos];

NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arInfos objectAtIndex:4]];

UIImage *Noimg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];
cell.img.image = Noimg;


cell.lblNome.text = [arInfos objectAtIndex:1];
cell.lblEndereco.text =[arInfos objectAtIndex:2];

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData *imgData,
                                               NSError * error)
    {
                               if (!error)
                               {
                                   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                                   cell.img.image = img;
                               }

                           }];
    }

      return cell;
  }
```

Comment: You might want to try insert NSLog inside cellForIndexPath and inside the completion handler. I bet most of your problems are because if async image loading.

Comment: Have you tried with SDWebImage..for loading imageURL in cell.imgView.image..!I think the request you used creating problems...

Comment: incorrect implementation of the async image loading. in the method your posted, the cell should read image from the model, in another method, willDisplayCellAtIndexPath, you should send out the async call and in the callback, save the image to the model

Comment: Hi, Everybody. Unfortunately I think the problem is not SDWebImage. I have tested the code with no async implementation, however it does not work. The problem has been kept.